# Reactivity of Object in primevue Dropdown

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, primevue

I have following setup:

Type:

```
export default interface Product {
    hostname: string,
    username: string,
    pub_key: string,
    image: {name: string, type: string},
}
```

Store:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import type Product from "@/types/product";
import type Flavor from "@/types/flavor";


export const useNewProductStore = defineStore('newProduct', {
    state: () => {
        return {
            provider: "",
            project: "",
            products: [] as Product[],
        }
    },
    getters: {
        getProvider(state) {
            return state.provider;
        },
        getProject(state) {
            return state.project;
        },
        getProducts(state) {
          return state.products;
        },
    },
    actions: {
        setProject(project: string) {
            this.project = project;
        },
        setProvider(provider: string) {
            this.provider = provider;
        },
        setProducts(products: Product[]) {
            this.products = products;
        },
        pushProduct(product: Product) {
            this.products.push(product)
        },
        popProduct() {
            this.products.pop();
        },
    }
})
```

Component:

```
<template>
<Card class="container" v-for="i in amount">
<template #content >
<Dropdown v-model="products[i-1].image" :options="images" option-label="name"
 placeholder="Select an image" :class="{'p-invalid': validationErrors.project && submitted}" style="width: 100%"/>
</template>
</Card>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {useNewProductStore} from "@/store/newProduct";
import {computed, onMounted, reactive, ref, watch} from "vue";

const products = computed({get() { return newProductStore.getProducts.map((obj:Product) => reactive(obj))}, set(value) {newProductStore.setProducts(value)}});
```

When I already have a product set from outside the component I want to go to the component with the Dropdown it will not show me the already set image. Instead it still shows me the Placeholder, but if I click on it I will see the right Image already selected. I guess it is a problem of reactivity, how can I ensure that if I already have a Product, the image inside the Product is already shown in the Dropdown instead of the placeholder?

Thanks alot for your help!